# Cannot pass object array to useState list

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, object, web

I am trying to pass a list of objects that I get from my server to a state list. When I print it out I see there are no values in the list, or sometimes it says it is undefined. Why is this happening and how can I solve it? Thanks.

````
    const favContext = useContext(FavoritesContext);

    const participantContext = useContext(ParticipantsContext);
    let [allPossibleParticipants, setAllPossibleParticipants] = useState([]);
    let [allParticipants, setAllParticipants] = useState([]);
    let [showParticipants, setShowParticipants] = useState(false);



    useEffect(() => {
        try {
            fetch('http://localhost:3000/users')
                .then(response => {
                    return response.json();
                }).then(data => {
                    const users = [];

                    for (const key in data) {
                        const user = {
                            id: key,
                            ...data[key]
                        };
                        users.push(user);
                    };
                    console.log(users);
                    setAllPossibleParticipants(users);
                    console.log(allPossibleParticipants);
                })
        } catch (err) { console.log(err) };
    }, [participantContext, props]);```

**Print Output:** 

Original object
{
    "id": "1",
    "_id": "60e5f9464711a474ccd0b592",
    "name": "Juan",
    "email": "juan.ucf.edu",
    "username": "juanucf1",
    "__v": 0
}

Receiving List

[]
````

Comment: Did you try to `console.log(data)`, to check whether it actually matches what you are expecting to receive?

Comment: `setAllPossibleParticipants(state => [...state, ...users]);`

Answer (score 1):

setState is asynchronous and may not have updated before your console.log statement.
Try moving your console.log outside the useEffect hook to see updates to your state.

Alternatively, you could also use another useEffect hook which will trigger whenever the state changes to view the updated state:

```
let [allPossibleParticipants, setAllPossibleParticipants] = useState([]);
    let [allParticipants, setAllParticipants] = useState([]);
    let [showParticipants, setShowParticipants] = useState(false);

useEffect(()=>{
    console.log(allPossibleParticipants)
},[allPossibleParticipants])

/// rest of your code
```

Comment: It's not because `setState` is asynchronous, it's because the closure keeps referring to the old value.

Answer (score 1):

It's because `useEffect` handler is closed over the value of `allParticipants` that was set at the time of its creation. So, whenever you refer to `allParticipants` you'll get the same value - it will never update through a setter.